Book about a girl(?) who lives in an underground house. Something happens to her family and she ends up wandering on the surface
I'm looking for a book I read as a kid in 2009-2012.
I don't remember a lot of details because I was only about nine when I read it, but the book follows a character (pretty sure it was a girl) who lives in an underground house. Something happens to her family and she ends up wandering on the surface. I remember her having a robot companion.
There was also an alphabet at the back of the book that I used when I was younger. The vibes were kind of slice of life Star Wars? That’s not very many details, I realize, but I've been searching for this for ages.

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

What was the surface world like? Like the real world? Futuristic? Post-apocalyptic? And did the main character's family initially live underground with them?

A long shot is The Book of Ember.  I don’t think that has an alphabet in the back, but am mentioning it just in case it rings a bell: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_City_of_Ember
